# Android notifications with multiple groups

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I implemented "Direct Reply" for the notifications in my app.
How do I implement multiple direct replies?

For example, if the user receives messages from two different people, I want him to be able to reply to each one of them through the notification.

Here is my code:

```
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text);
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle expandedStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
expandedStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
for (String key : mMessageList.keySet()) {
    for (String message : mMessageList.get(key)) {
        expandedStyle.addLine(message);
    }
}
expandedStyle.setSummaryText(summary);
notificationBuilder.setStyle(expandedStyle);

String replyLabel = context.getString(R.string.reply_to, name);
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
                .setLabel(replyLabel)
                .build();

NotificationCompat.Action replyAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                R.drawable.reply, replyLabel, getReplyPendingIntent(context))
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .build();

notificationBuilder.addAction(replyAction);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539297/how-to-display-multiple-notification-as-a-group) this shows how to build multiple notification.

Answer (score -1):

When creating multiple notifications for a handheld device, you should always aggregate similar notifications into a single summary notification.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539297/how-to-display-multiple-notification-as-a-group) this shows how to build multiple notification as groups.