# Android Group Notification having multiple messages -Wierd action button issue

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

In our application we have multiple notifications being grouped into a single notification which shows summary of each message on each line, on click of group notification we get more details of each notification message. When we expand notification associated with single message the action buttons are visible.

Currently we are facing problem when performing action on single message in group message all the unread messages are getting removed from the notification drawer although we are giving the unique notification id of the message which need to be removed in notificatinmanager.cancel() method.

Our code is pretty similar to the code used here(second answer in this post) :
[How to display multiple notification as a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539297/how-to-display-multiple-notification-as-a-group)